# Invalid Type and incorrect signature error in Future class

Tags: apex, callout, future

Hi we have a @future class created, however we have this error as per the screen shot below

[image]

Please find the code below

```
public with sharing class Addressfuture {

public Addressfuture()
{
    List<String> Addresses = new List<String>();
    AddressHelper obj1 = new AddressHelper('1 hase st','san Francisco','CA','94105');
    AddressHelper obj2 = new AddressHelper('2 hase st','San francisco','CA','94105');
    AddressHelper obj3 = new AddressHelper('3 hase st','San francisco','CA','94105');

    Addresses.add(JSON.serialize(obj1));
    Addresses.add(JSON.serialize(obj2));
    Addresses.add(JSON.serialize(obj3));
    callfuture(Addresses);
}

@future
Static void callfuture(List<String> Addresses)
{
    Address currAddress = null;
    for(String sur: Addresses)
    {
        currAddress =(Address)JSON.deserialize(sur,AddressHelper.class);
        system.debug('Deserialized in future:' +currAddress.street);
    }
}
```

}

```
public with Sharing class Address {

public string street{get;set;}
public string city{get;set;}
public string state{get;set;}
public string zip{get;set;}

Public Address(string s,String c,String st,String z)
{
    Street = s;
    City = c;
    State = st;
    Zip = z;
}
```

}

Please advise

Thanks,

Comment: Can you also post the code of `AddressHelper` class?

Comment: Where is your AddressHelper class defined? The error you're seeing occurs because the AddressHelper class isn't accessible in the code you're calling it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use constructor of `Address` class, instead you are looking for `AddressHelper`. Please correct it in your code and it would work.

Instead of

`AddressHelper obj1 = new AddressHelper('1 hase st','san Francisco','CA','94105');`

use:

```
Address obj1 = new Address('1 hase st','san Francisco','CA','94105');
```